# Setting default collation method in MySQL Workbench doesn't change the collation method

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench to design my MySQL schema and I need my database to be case-sensitive. I have set the default collation method to `latin1_general_cs`, `latin1_bin`, and `utf8_bin` to no avail. When I check the collation version in MySQL by using the command `SELECT collation(version())`, it returns

```
mysql> select collation(version());
+----------------------+
| collation(version()) |
+----------------------+
| utf8_general_ci      |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Regardless of what default method I have chosen.

When I do the following search:

```
mysql> select * from table_name where t_name = "search_request";
```

I get back `SEARCH_REQUEST`, as well as `search_request`.

However, if I use the command

```
mysql> select * from table_name where t_name = "search_request" collate utf8_bin;
```

I get the anticipated result, `search_request`.

By the way, in my `.sql` file, I see the following:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `database_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin ;
USE `database_name` ;
```

which makes me incredibly confused why I am not seeing the correct results or the correct default collation method. Any ideas?

Comment: `select collation(version());` won't help you returning the server's collation. Because of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_version), it will always return utf8. Try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';`

Comment: This still doesn't explain why I'm not seeing the correct results, even if the `select collation(version())` doesn't show the current collation (which I understand from your link), MySQL statements should still work according to the default schema collation that I'm giving it. In other words, if I tell it to use `utf8_bin`, it should be returning case-sensitive results. In fact, I figured out why this is the case and I will be adding my answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was that I wasn't dropping my database schema before reinitializing it, so the changes weren't propagated to the current database.

Simply adding this command to the start of my `.sql` script:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `database_name` ;
```

Fixed my problem and I was able to make case-sensitive queries!